# How to read the current value of a computed property within that computed property method?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

We would like to enable a query once a string has more than 3 characters. Once the query is enabled, it should stay enabled. Using the Vue 2 Composition API we created a `reactive` object with the status of the queries:

```js
import { computed, defineComponent, reactive, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const truckId = ref<string>('')
    const driverId = ref<string>('')

    const queryEnabled = reactive({
      driver: false,
      truck: false,
    })
```

Now to set the value for `queryEnabled.driver` to `true` when `driverId` is a string with a length longer than 3 characters we can do this:

```js
    const queryEnabled = reactive({
      driver: computed(() => driverId.value.length >= 3),
      truck: false,
    })
```

This works but it also sets `queryEnabled.driver`to `false` once the string has less characters. How can we have a `computed` property that:

- starts with `false`
- sets the value to `true` once a condition is met
- keeps the value to `true` once it was set before and doesn't change it back

Can this be done from within only one `computed` property in the `reactive` object? I was thinking with a `function` instead of a fat arrow to access `this` for the current `computed` property but can't figure it out.

Comment: Can't you use `watcheffect` with `reactive` in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get access to the `computed` property from within itself, so use `watch` to update the state based on `driverId`:

```js
import { watch, defineComponent, reactive, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const truckId = ref<string>('')
    const driverId = ref<string>('')

    const queryEnabled = reactive({
      driver: false,
      truck: false,
    })

    watch(driverId,(newVal)=>{
      if(!queryEnabled.driver && newVal.length >= 3){
        queryEnabled.driver = true
      }
    })
```

Comment: That is definitely an option. But I was hoping this was possible from within a single `computed` property.

Comment: `computed` prop isn't assumed to be "unchangable".

Comment: I was thinking about a computed with get and set options but that doesn't give a solution

Comment: @DarkLite1 let's assume that we can get access to the property within itself that could make an infinite loop, this is like `sum=a+b` we can't access the sum in the right side